# Maximum RAM supported by CPU/Chipset varies in Intel Datasheets?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I understand the questions is asked here often and I have read all of them regarding, the picture wasn't clear though.

As per the manufacturer the laptop supports 16GB (8GB soldered, 1 extra 8GB slot), but as per the intel's i7 6700 HQ page the maximum RAM supported is 64GB, and as per intel's product document for Skylake-H chipset the maximum is 32GB, and as per the DDR4 information in the same document the maximum is 16GB. Basically it's going round and round and round, I also used the dmidecode tool which also shows as 64GB maximum RAM.

Many people are adding more, and I too want to add more probably the maximum supported but without taking any risk and avoiding loss if more RAM is not supported.

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88967/intel-core-i7-6700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html

[H-Platform Datasheet 1](https://docdro.id/wlixgmD)

[H-Platform Datasheet 2](https://docdro.id/Q1aUUfk)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The reason for this question is that if the board supports 64GB than I'd need a 32GB to make it 40GB RAM since 1 8GB is already soldered (as I wouldn't find a 56GB RAM module to make it 64GB), if its 32 GB then I need 1 16GB for the same to make it 24GB.

Comment: Actually, your question is titled wrong. There’s only one source that says something about the amount of RAM your motherboard supports, which is the ASUS documentation for your laptop. The other sources are about your CPU and Chipset but they say nothing about the amount of RAM that will actually fit and function *in your specific model of laptop*. More RAM might work, but it just as well might not.

Comment: The question refers to Intel i7 6700 notes on RAM and Skylake-H notes on RAM, but thanks for point that out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the different information is because the two sources are for two **completely different things**.

Your processor supports 64GB of RAM. It does. But that is for a specified configuration, most likely two channels of RAM with two DIMMs per channel. That would probably be for 16GB DIMMs.

Your motherboard on the other hand has two channels, one soldered and one not, but only one DIMM wired up per channel.

You *might* be able to fit a 16GB DIMM instead of an 8, but you may loose some of the benefits of dual channel RAM. You might trade amount of memory for overall speed.

What your processor *can* support is not the same as what you motherboard was *designed* to support.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, where the chipset memory support on the motherboard come in the picture ?

Comment: The chipset determines what processor you can use. The memory controller is in your cpu but can only use what is physically wired up in your motherboard.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying all that, I think I'm getting the picture now.